# Re-use arrow function to write values

Tags: javascript

If I have an arrow function like:

```
let fn = x => x.contact.name;
```

Then, I can re-use that `fn` to retrieve the value as:

```
function read(obj) {
    return fn(obj)
}
```

But how can I set values of an object using the property expression in `fn`?

```
function write(obj, newVal) {
    // intending to set obj.contact.name = newVal using fn
}
```

Edit:

(To give a little bit of background)

I am writing a JS library where consumers would provide a lambda expression like above (`fn`), and I provide a read/write functionality somewhere based on the expression. Right now I am using `fn.toString()` and string manipulation as a temporary solution.

Comment: you can use bracket notation

Comment: You can't, not as is.

Comment: We don't have inverse functions (`f^-1`). The best thing you can have is a setter function.

Comment: Only possible if `newVal` is also an object just like `obj`, which means `newVal` should also have `contact.name` property. So that you can do `obj.contact.name = fn(newVal)`

Comment: You might be looking for lenses

Comment: @TalESid The issue with that is, you cannot deduct `obj.contact.name` part. I wanted to re-use the expression in `fn`

Comment: You can't. `fn` is a function that takes an object and returns a value. You can only "reuse" that function as a whole, not parts of it. You can call it with different objects and use its return value. No more, no less.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, [lenses](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/lenses-b85976cb0534) need two callbacks, get and set, because (in javascript at least) functions are not permitted to return references. For simple cases, like getting/setting a property, you can provide a shortcut function that would return a getter/setter pair. For example:

```js
function prop(path) {
    return {
        get(obj) {
            return path.split('.').reduce((o, p) => o[p], obj)
        },
        set(val) {
            return function (obj) {
                let p = path.split('.')
                let k = p.pop()
                let r = p.reduce((o, p) => o[p], obj)
                r[k] = val
            }
        }
    }
}

//

obj1 = { contact: { name: 'one' }}
obj2 = { contact: { name: 'two' }}


let lens = prop('contact.name')

console.log([obj1, obj2].map(lens.get));

[obj1, obj2].forEach(lens.set('hello'));

console.log([obj1, obj2].map(lens.get));
```

See also: https://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/07/12/thinking-in-ramda-lenses/

Answer (score 1):

The below two functions are almost entirely the same:

```js
let fn = x => x.contact.name;

function fn(x) {
  return x.contact.name;
}
```

As such, you can't use a function that returns an object property to set the object property.

Instead consider the following two functions:

```js
let fn = (x, newVal) => {
  if (newVal) x.contact.name = newVal;
  return x.contact.name;
};

/* - This function included just for reference -
function fn(x, newVal) {
  if (newVal) x.contact.name = newVal;
  return x.contact.name;
}
*/

let myObj = { contact: { name: "Jess" } };

console.log(fn(myObj)); // name currently
fn(myObj, "John"); // set new name
console.log(myObj); // show new name on object
```

Comment: You're not wrong, but I can't imagine wanting to leave a contact's name as an empty string - that seems like the kind of thing you'd want to `delete` or set to `null`.

Comment: `fn(myObj, null)` doesn't work either. I mean that your condition is broken, and that `fn` should have no say in what values are considered valid or not.

Comment: The above code works. But I was expecting to get the `fn` expression from consumers of my library. And requiring all of them to write like above is a bit much to ask.

Comment: Again, I'm aware - both resolve as falsy in the if statement. This does not seem to be a requirement of the OP. If that changes, I'll adjust the code. @Bergi

Comment: @Leone if you ONLY want to set values, you can do so with this: `let fn = (x, y) => x.contacts.name = y;` but this will allow users to set the value to booleans, null properties, etc.

Comment: @LaytonGB Nothing in their question hints at an exception for falsy values, or really any exception at all

Comment: @Bergi I recommend writing your own answer.

Comment: @LaytonGB Updated my question to give you a bit of background and my intentions.

Comment: @LaytonGB Sorry to budge into this ;) And though Leone as commented... but maybe checking for the number of passed arguments might be a better test for whether it's a write or read operation. This way it's irrelevant what *falsy* value might be used to write.

Comment: @Leone The updated post is much more clear, but I don't know a better method than your current one. I'll leave this post here for posterity unless it gets downvoted in which case I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following will do what you want?

I had to change the "lambda" expression a little bit, as it would not make much sense to give the return value of the original function to a potential "write" function, as it was a *value* and not a reference. My "new" function definition of `fn` works differently: it returns an array with two elements:

1. the "parent" *object* containing a particular attribute
2. the *name* of the attribute of the object.

The functions `read()` and `write()` can then pick up the return values of `fn(o)` and perform their particular actions accordingly.

```js
let fn = x => [x.contact,"name"];

const read=o=>fn(o)[0][fn(o)[1]]         // get the attribute as defined in fn
     ,write=(o,v)=>fn(o)[0][fn(o)[1]]=v; // set the attribute as defined in fn     

const o={contact:{name:"Harry",country:"England"}};

console.log(read(o));
write(o,"Hermiony");
console.log(read(o));

// change the lambda function:
fn = x => [x.contact,"country"];

write(o,"Germany");

console.log(read(o));
console.log(o);
```